# About citymaps questions

Tags: citymaps

I have some new questions about the citymaps。

1、I am not need your business layer function，what I need is that the animation of the business marker show and hide，I want to add some markers to the citymaps and when I enlarge the map，some other markers showing，on the contrary, some markers are hide when I shrink the maps。

2、I found a surprise appearence is that I have built a marker at fix position，but when I shrink the maps，the marker move from current position to the sea and move back if I enlarge，why is it so？

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer on the Citymaps SDK and I will do my best to answer your questions.

1) The internal functionality of the `BusinessLayer` is not accessible via the APIs.  If you want to create this animation, it can be accomplished by animating the `alpha` and `scale` properties of your marker.

2) This is likely due to your marker's anchor point.  Markers will be pinned to the map at their anchor point, which is a coordinate relative to the marker's size, scaling from 0 to 1 in both directions.  For instance,  you will probably notice the top left corner of your marker is pinned to the same location.  You can read about anchor points in our documentation here:
http://developer.citymaps.com/markers#anchor-points